# Adding internal spaces in pyplot legend

Tags: python, text, matplotlib, legend

I would like to justify a legend so that it is both left and right aligned and so that the equals are aligned.  For example I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

KEu = 100.
KEm = 50.
KEl = 5.
X   = np.linspace(1,10,10) 

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.plot(X,KEu*X,label='Maximum Energy = {0:6.2f} MeV'.format(KEu))
ax.plot(X,KEm*X,label='Median Energy  = {0:6.2f} MeV'.format(KEm))
ax.plot(X,KEl*X,label='Minimum Energy = {0:6.2f} MeV'.format(KEl))
ax.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

I don't know how to add a plot so I will give a written example below:

```
-- Maximum Energy = 100.00 MeV  
-- Median Energy = 50.00 MeV     
-- Minimum Energy = 5.00 MeV
```

The quotes seem to be necessary to post this otherwise SO thinks it is poorly formatted code.  The dashes represent lines.

I would like to have it left justified, with the ='s aligned and the decimals aligned.  Something like:

```
-- Maximum Energy = 100.00 MeV
-- Median Energy  =  50.00 MeV  
-- Minimum Energy =   5.00 MeV
```

Of course that isn't perfect, and may be the best I could do in my plot, but i like it better than the original.

I assume I will need to do this manually so I have tried to add white space, I have tried combining strings with one left justified and the other right justified, but no success.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible for fixed-width fonts, i.e., `monospace`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

KEu = 100.
KEm = 50.
KEl = 5.
X   = np.linspace(1,10,10) 

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.plot(X,KEu*X,label=r"Maximum Energy = {0:6.2f} MeV".format(KEu))
ax.plot(X,KEm*X,label=r"Median  Energy = {0:6.2f} MeV".format(KEm))
ax.plot(X,KEl*X,label=r"Minimum Energy = {0:6.2f} MeV".format(KEl))
ax.legend(loc='upper left', prop={'family': 'monospace'})
plt.show()
```

[image]