# Aligning text in rows of Pyplot legend at multiple points, without using monospace font

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I am trying to create a neat legend in Pyplot. So far I have this:

[image: Legend]

```
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = plt.gca()

    marker_size = [20.0, 40.0, 60.0, 100.0, 150.0]                              
    marker_color = ['black', 'red', 'pink', 'white', 'yellow']                  
                                                                                
    ranges = [0.0, 1.5, 20.0, 60.0, 500.0]                                      
                                                                                
    marker_edge_thickness = 1.2                                                 
    s = [(m ** 2) / 100.0 for m in marker_size]                                 
    scatter_kwargs = {'edgecolors' : 'k', 'linewidths' : marker_edge_thickness} 
                                                                                
    for i in range(len(marker_size)):                                           
                                                                                
        if i == (len(marker_size) - 1):                                         
                                                                                
            label_str = '{:>5.1f} $\leq$ H$_2$'.format(ranges[i])               
                                                                                
        else:                                                                   
                                                                                
            label_str = '{:>5.1f} $\leq$ H$_2$ < {:>5.1f}'.format(ranges[i], ranges[i + 1]) 
                                                                                
        ax.scatter([], [], s = s[i], c = marker_color[i],                       
                label = label_str, **scatter_kwargs)                            
                                                                                
    #ax.legend(prop={'family': 'monospace'})                                    
    ax.legend()
                                                                 
    plt.show()
```

It is ok but the symbols don't align properly between the rows. I would like to align the rows at multiple points, with alignment on the decimal points, the less-than and greater-than symbols, and the H2. I could use a monotype font (as per this answer: [Adding internal spaces in pyplot legend](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37353663/19979370)), but this is ugly and seems to be incompatible with the subscript 2 in H2. This would be possible in LaTeX (e.g. using the `alignat` environment); is it possible in Pyplot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could replace the spaces by `'\u2007'`, [a space that is as wide as a digit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figure_space).

In most fonts, a space character is much narrower than a digit. Except for monospaced fonts, which don't look as nice, each letter has its own width. The character width can even be different depending on which letter goes before and after (E.g. with 'VA', the 'A' can be a bit under the 'V', this is called ["kerning"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning)). Special characters are introduced in UTF-8 for spaces with a specific width.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()

marker_size = [20.0, 40.0, 60.0, 100.0, 150.0]
marker_color = ['black', 'red', 'pink', 'white', 'yellow']

ranges = [0.0, 1.5, 20.0, 60.0, 500.0]

marker_edge_thickness = 1.2
s = [(m ** 2) / 100.0 for m in marker_size]
scatter_kwargs = {'edgecolors': 'k', 'linewidths': marker_edge_thickness}

for i in range(len(marker_size)):
     label_str = f"{ranges[i]:>5.1f}$\leq$H$_2$"
     if i < (len(marker_size) - 1):
          label_str += f"$<${ranges[i + 1]:>5.1f}"
     label_str = label_str.replace(' ', '\u2007')
     ax.scatter([], [], s=s[i], c=marker_color[i], label=label_str, **scatter_kwargs)

ax.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: aligning text in legend]

Comment: This works perfectly in my case using the Pyplot default font, although I don't think it would work for fonts where the numerical characters (1, 2, ...) have different widths.

Answer (score 2):

This uses monospace type, but at least uses the appropriate font for the subscript of H

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()

marker_size = [20.0, 40.0, 60.0, 100.0, 150.0]                              
marker_color = ['black', 'red', 'pink', 'white', 'yellow']                  

ranges = [0.0, 1.5, 20.0, 60.0, 500.0]             
num_digits = [1,1,2,2,3]

marker_edge_thickness = 1.2                                                 
s = [(m ** 2) / 100.0 for m in marker_size]                                 
scatter_kwargs = {'edgecolors' : 'k', 'linewidths' : marker_edge_thickness} 

for i in range(len(marker_size)):                                           
    if i == (len(marker_size) - 1):                                         
        label_str = '{:.1f}$\leq \mathregular{}$'.format(ranges[i],r'{\ H_2\ }')               
    else:                   
        label_str = '{:>5.1f}$\leq \mathregular{}<${:>5.1f}'.format(ranges[i], r'{\ H_2\ }',ranges[i + 1])
    ax.scatter([], [], s = s[i], c = marker_color[i],                       
            label = label_str, **scatter_kwargs)                            

ax.legend(prop={'family': 'monospace'})
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I prefer the other answer, as it allows me to avoid the monospaced font (the monospace isn't really obvious here except for the dots inside the zeros, but once I add a title to the legend, it is obvious, and although it is possible to change the legend title font separately, it is harder to do so). However, it is still useful to know how to put the subscript into other monospaced text, thanks!

Comment: @harry.kuril Agreed. Glad to help!